# Testing floating point equality with AssertWasCalled

Tags: c#, floating-point, rhino-mocks

I have a test that ends with this:

```
model.AssertWasCalled(m => m.CalculateBeta(
    Arg<double>.Is.Equal(50),
    Arg<double>.Is.Equal(3.74593228));
```

I would like to test this using a delta value like what is provided in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert

```
Assert.AreEqual(3.745932, result, 0.000001);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there is an easier way:

```
test.AssertWasCalled(
    t => t.CalculateBeta(
        Arg<double>.Matches(a => Math.Abs(a - 50) < 0.01),
        Arg<double>.Matches(b => Math.Abs(b - 3.74593228) < 0.000001)
    )
);
```

Actually, you can pass any predicate to `Arg<T>.Matches()` to validate each argument particulary.

Comment: Not sure why this didn't occur to me. I'm almost embarrassed to leave my post down there :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this atrocity. Would love to see some better solutions.

```
var values = new List<Tuple<double, double>>
{
    Tuple.Create(50.0, 0.1),
    Tuple.Create(3.745932, 0.000001),
};
Predicate<double> expected = (x) =>
{
    var value = values[0];
    values.RemoveAt(0);

    Assert.AreEqual(value.Item1, x, value.Item2);
    return true;
};
model.AssertWasCalled(m => m.CalculateBeta(
    Arg<double>.Matches((x) => expected(x)),
    Arg<double>.Matches((x) => expected(x));
```